# XML and DTD: The content of the type element must match

Tags: xml, dtd

Im a Spanish Web Developer student first of all sorry my bad english but I will try my best for explain that problem.

We started the markups languagues and we need create an XML document and DTD for validating that XML.

[image]

This is my XML who im trying to validate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/XML/XMLDocument.xml to edit this template
-->

<!DOCTYPE academia SYSTEM "actividad2_dtd.dtd">

<academia>
    <matriculas>
        <matricula>
            <cod_matricula>M83928971-22</cod_matricula>
        
            <administrativo>
                <nombre_administrativo>Francisco Javier Ruiz Barrosa</nombre_administrativo>
                <dni_administrativo>62637169V</dni_administrativo>
            </administrativo>
        
            <fecha_matricula>14/09/2022</fecha_matricula>
            <importe_matricula moneda = "Euro">59,67</importe_matricula>
            <pago forma="Transferencia"/>    //Paypal, Bizum, Tarjeta, Trasnferencia
            <metodo_envio modo="Urgente"/>
            <fecha_entrega></fecha_entrega>
            <observaciones>Matricula Parcial</observaciones>   //Opcional    
        </matricula>
          
        <alumnado>
            <alumno>
                <identificacion>
                    <cod_alumno>RG8293</cod_alumno>
                    <fecha_nacimiento>05/03/1998</fecha_nacimiento>
                    <dni_alumno>53584168X</dni_alumno>       //Opcional
                </identificacion>
                <tipo_curso>completo</tipo_curso>
                <nombre_completo>
                    <nombre_alumno>Juan Pablo</nombre_alumno>
                    <primer_apellido>Sanchez</primer_apellido>
                    <segundo_apellido>Valdes</segundo_apellido>
                </nombre_completo>
                <direccion>
                    <via>Calle Trebujena</via>
                    <numero_via>14</numero_via>
                    <localidad>Chipiona</localidad>
                    <provincia>Cádiz</provincia>
                    <codigo_postal>11550</codigo_postal>
                </direccion>
       
                <telefono>
                    <movil></movil>
                    <fijo></fijo>
                </telefono>
              
                <repetidor>
                    <repite>Si</repite>
                    <numero_repeticiones>1</numero_repeticiones>
                </repetidor>
            </alumno>
        </alumnado>
    
        <cursos>
            <curso>
                <cod_curso>CAL1988-45</cod_curso>
                <idioma>Ingles</idioma>
                <nivel>A1</nivel>
                <precio moneda="Euro"></precio>
            </curso>
        </cursos>
    

    </matriculas>
    
</academia>
```

And this is my DTD who i make it for validate the XML document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/XML/emptyDTD.dtd to edit this template
-->

<!--
    TODO define vocabulary identification data
    PUBLIC ID  : -//vendor//vocabulary//EN
    SYSTEM ID  : http://server/path/__NAME__
-->

<!-- TODO define your own vocabulary/syntax. Example follows:  -->
<!ELEMENT academia (matriculas)>
<!ELEMENT matriculas (matricula, alumnado, cursos)>
<!ELEMENT matricula (cod_matricula, administrativo, fecha_matricula, importe_matricula, pago, metodo_envio, fecha_entrega, observaciones?)>
<!ELEMENT cod_matricula (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT administrativo (nombre_administrativo, dni_administrativo)>
<!ELEMENT nombre_administrativo (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT dni_administrativo (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT fecha_matricula (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT importe_matricula (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST importe_matricula moneda CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT pago (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST pago forma (Paypal|Bizum|Tarjeta|Transferencia) #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT metodo_envio (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST metodo_envio modo CDATA #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT fecha_entrega (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT observaciones (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT alumnado (alumno)>
<!ELEMENT alumno (indentificacion, tipo_curso, nombre_completo, direccion, telefono, repetidor )>
<!ELEMENT identificacion (cod_alumno, fecha_nacimiento, dni_alumno?)>
<!ELEMENT cod_alumno (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT fecha_nacimiento (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT dni_alumno (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT tipo_curso (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT nombre_completo (nombre_alumno, primer_apellido, segundo_apellido)>
<!ELEMENT nombre_alumno (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT primer_apellido (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT segundo_apellido (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT direccion (via, numero_via, localidad, provincia, codigo_postal)>
<!ELEMENT via (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT numero_via (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT localidad (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT provincia (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT codigo_postal (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT telefono (movil,fijo?)>
<!ELEMENT movil (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT fijo (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT repetidor (repite,numero_repeticiones)>
<!ELEMENT repite (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT numero_repeticiones (#PCDATA)>


<!ELEMENT cursos (curso)>
<!ELEMENT curso (cod_curso,idioma,nivel,precio)>
<!ELEMENT cod_curso (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT idioma (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT nivel (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT precio (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST precio moneda CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

So at the moment I dont know where is my fail because I see the same content in the elements "matricula" "indentificacion" and "alumno" I dont know if its because at the moment I have mental block or anything but seriusly I dont understand where is my fail.

If dont understant the code for the spanish words I could change to english if anyone need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `indentificacion` misspelled in DTD. Should be `identificacion`
2. On XML: `//Paypal, Bizum, Tarjeta, Trasnferencia` is PCDATA from XML perspective. Could be `<!-- Paypal, Bizum, Tarjeta, Trasnferencia -->`. Same for other `//`cases.

Comment: Thanks! Oh my god, I was really frustating checking the code but not check the spell of the words.  However the other thing taht you mentioned was useful, because if I use the // for comments I got validation error to.  But, now I have few questions, at the hour of work with these markups languagues, usually the formation of DTD is first than a the XML formation? And I have other tools for comment? I dont like <!--COMENT--> structure.

Comment: DTD/XSD are used to define XML structure and for validation but are not mandatory. Read about  Well Formed vs Valid XML. Comments are `<!--COMENT can span several lines -->` only. If you remove `<!DOCTYPE academia SYSTEM "actividad2_dtd.dtd">` form the XML it will still be a well formed XML.